# Failed to get device attribute 13 for device 0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

When I'm trying to run Yolo detection examples, I got that error:

```
2020-02-02 21:39:00.821721: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll                                                                                                                  
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Dominux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1635: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.                                                                        
Instructions for updating:                                                                                                       
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.                                                                            
2020-02-02 21:39:03.863436: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll                                                                                                                        
2020-02-02 21:39:04.431694: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:             
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: GeForce MX230 computeCapability: 6.1                                                                
coreClock: 1.531GHz coreCount: 2 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 44.76GiB/s                                     
2020-02-02 21:39:04.437212: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll                                                                                                                  
2020-02-02 21:39:04.444498: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll                                                                                                                   
2020-02-02 21:39:04.450110: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll                                                                                                                    
2020-02-02 21:39:04.453997: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll                                                                                                                   
2020-02-02 21:39:04.459404: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll                                                                                                                 
2020-02-02 21:39:04.464501: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll                                                                                                                 
2020-02-02 21:39:04.477818: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll                                                                                                                     
2020-02-02 21:39:04.480586: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0               
2020-02-02 21:39:09.674559: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2                                                                                         
2020-02-02 21:39:09.678508: F tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/statusor.cc:34] Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error 
Internal: failed to get device attribute 13 for device 0: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
```

My stack:

- Win 10,
- Tensoflow 2.1,
- Intel Core I5,
- Nvidia GeForce MX230 2GB,
- 8GD DDR4

I checked similar issues, but they don't have solutions. Just despaired people...
But it problem was talked about by them only with TF 1.14 - I didn't find other
But how you could notice at me stack above I'm using TF 2.1 already

Please, can you help me!
Maybe I've got problems with drivers or CUDA software?
Any ideas?

Comment: My anaconda 2019.3 was wacked (would no longer upgrade, windged about "inconsistency" on every package). It was working with GPU on this box (Windows 10, CUDA 10.1, GTX 850M). I upgraded to anaconda 2020.02 tensorflow 2.1 and now I'm getting exactly this same error with this very simple command: import tensorflow as tf ; sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(). After the error the python session blows off.

Comment: very simple import tensorflow as tf ; tf.device('/device:GPU:0') will blow off the very same way. GPU type and bandwidth is reported, so it looks like something is working.

Answer (score 3):

update the driver to the latest version works！！！
and you can use NVIDIA GeForce Experience to do this

Comment: Could you explain why you think this solution is correct for the situation?

Answer (score 2):

Bingo! updated my driver from 418.91 to 445.75 (latest) and now it leaps to life.

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me. Thanks for the resolution.