# Tensorflow Cuda Error failed to get device attribute 13 for device 0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.x

I am facing problem while training neural networks using tensorflow-keras. I am getting this error:

> F tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/statusor.cc:34] Attempting to fetch
>   value instead of handling error Internal: failed to get device
>   attribute 13 for device 0: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error

I was getting this error initially. Then I referred to the solution in [failed-to-get-device-attribute-13-for-device-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034181/failed-to-get-device-attribute-13-for-device-0). I updated the graphics driver. This worked for some 3-4 runs and now I am getting the same error again.

Following are the details of my environment:

1. Python 3.7 (Anaconda)
2. Tensorflow 2.1
3. Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060, 6GB Graphics
4. Windows 10 Version 1809

Comment: what version of cuda drivers you have? what is the output of `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: Driver Version: 431.23; CUDA Version: 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case limiting the GPU memory worked.

Add the following code segment at the beginning of your code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
```

Comment: Tried it. It works for some runs then I receive this status again. I have also observed that if I have 2 editors with programs needing GPUs ('not running', Visual Code and Pycharm with same virtual env), I am getting this error, although there is no concrete reason but purely observation.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i was sending my tf models to cuda. My error was resolved when i used.

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
```

Instead of

```
with tf.device("cuda"):
```

So instead of cuda just specify the it like this **/gpu:0**. If you have multiple GPU's just check the tensorflow proper installation from the docs.

After installation, Add this after tf import

```
mirrored_strategy = tensorflow.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
```

& It should automatically detect multiple GPU's